# How to fetch all profile metadata including object permission, field permisssion, record type etc. using Salesforce Tooling API

Tags: apex, soql, tooling-api

I am using workbench to retrieve a user profile using tooling API, but unable to retrieve any data in fieldPermissions, objectPermissions or recordTypeVisibilities files.
Can anyone suggest me how to fetch all these details using Tooling API?

Comment: Why are you using the Tooling API rather than just using SOQL?

Comment: My goal is to develop a tool that compares the profiles from two different sandbox instances of a salesforce org. And by using SOQL i am only able to get boolean fields value like PermissionsEditPublicTemplates, PermissionsModifyAllData etc. but not getting any CRUD permission data for sobjects.

Comment: Are you sure about that? This question would be vastly improved if you **[edit]** it to provide increased detail about what you built out that led you to that conclusion.